# exit() Doesn't work?

Tags: php, http, header

I have this php script it's not inside a function

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num == 0) 
{
    header("Location:index.php#captcha");//Location:#errorlogin.html");
    $_POST[password]="";
    exit;
}
```

It always seems to  continue executing everything after this part regardless of $num being equal to 0 I have already tried exit("message"), die, return etc. Sorry if it's a noobish question haha

Answer (score 3):

You're [redirecting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) the page.

An example to notice from [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) page:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$_POST[password]="";
```

That should probably be (note the `'`):

```
$_POST['password'] = "";
```

The function `exit()` definitely stops execution when it is executed. There must be something wrong with your if condition.

In PHP multiple values "equal" to zero (if you use `==`). Try `var_dump($num)` to see what's really in there.

Comment: @Madmadmax That _does_ make sense. In this case the if condition will be false and thus `exit()` won't be executed.

Answer (score 2):

`exit` would not working because it is has 2 dependency

A. `if ($num == 0)`  if `$num` is not zero exit would not work

B. `header("Location:index.php#captcha");` If your location works exit would not wort

try

```
$num = mysql_num_rows ( $result );
if ($num == 0) {
    $_POST ['password'] = null;
    header ( "Location: http://yoursite.com/index.php#captcha" ); // Location:#errorlogin.html");
    exit();
}
else
{
    echo "Found $num in the database";
}
```